# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un LIMIT dinámico en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando hacer algo como esto:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(NUM) FROM...)T;
```

Se trata de hacer un límite en función del número de registros que haya en otra tabla, es decir, pasarle a LIMIT un valor devuelto por una subconsulta. Esto en SQL Server con TOP no hay problema, pero veo que MySQL no lo permite. Ni siquiera aplicando una variable intermedia que almacene el valor de la subconsulta. ¿Hay forma de indicarle a la cláusula LIMIT un valor dinámico?

P.D: MariaDB tampoco lo permite :(, lo he probado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Y si concatenas todo y lo ejecutas en un bloque de transacción? Algo como

```
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;
  SET @valor_limit = 0;
  SELECT ... INTO @valor_limit;
  SELECT concat('SELECT ... LIMIT ', @valor_limit) INTO @sql;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

Comment: Efectivamente, sí funciona perfectamente. Gracias Alfabravo

Comment: Para `@sql` ¿Por qué hacer SELECT-INTO cuando puedes asignar el valor directo de la concatenación `SET @sql = concat('SELECT ...', @limite);`?

Answer (score 3):

El `LIMIT` es una de esas clausulas que no pueden resolverse por variable, sino que tiene que establecerse de forma literal, por lo que la única posibilidad es la que te comentaron más arriba, las sentencias dinámicas.

De todas formas, en la última versión de `mysql` o en `Mariadb` puedes simular algo parecido a `LIMIT` mediante el uso de la función `ROW_NUMBER()` y una subconsulta o una expresión de tabla:

```
set @num=10;

WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT table_name, table_type, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name) as rn 
       FROM information_schema.tables 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn <= @num;
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio, es una alternativa curiosa también.

Answer (score 3):

En las sentencias dinámicas puedes usar la cláusula `USING`:

```
SELECT 2
  INTO @limite;

PREPARE stmt 
  FROM 'SELECT 1 col UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 LIMIT ?';

EXECUTE stmt USING @limite;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Resultado:

```
+-----+
| col |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
+-----+
```

Comment: Buen matiz Sal.